# How to access individual elements of a Tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a model in Keras, where the output of one of the layers gives me the coordinates of a mask that I want to apply on the image input. The problem is that I could not find any way to do this, methods such as `tf.slice()` do not work if you are not inside a session.

I want to do equivalent to this:

```
x=dense(2)(x)
A=np.zeros((224,224, 3)) or K.zeros((224,224,3))
x=int(x)
A[x[0],x[1],:]=1
```

where x comes from previous layers and is reassigned in the layer shown (dense layer from keras), the output is two numbers representing the position in the picture, then I create A which is  a mask to be multiplied with the input (input not shown), and I need both, make the output of the layer an integer, and then use it to add ones to the mask A at position (x[0],x[1]) (and other ones too, but just having one is enough to know the method.

Comment: Just some clarifications: is dense here the imported Keras layer type "Dense"? Is x an input (values, another layer), that you are then reassigning to the variable x? Maybe some more description of your expected outputs or comments inline would help. I'm having a hard time understanding what you expect from the source provided here

Comment: thanks for the comment, I will clarify

Comment: It doesn’t seem like the model you’ve constructed ever gets compiled or evaluated. Isn’t x in the first line still a tensor? You’ll need to provide that tensor it’s expected inputs to fill the missing placeholders. Do you have some sample value of x (before the code block you shared) to nail down the missing placeholder values?

Comment: In keras you create a "model" that is later compiled. I believe that the placeholders are all inside the API, you never explicitly mention them, x is the input to the model, and I am not sure how it works but it is a numpy array converted into a Keras Tensor.   Layers only accept outputs of previous layers, all keras tensors. I believe is a x is placeholder because you never give it a value until you train the model, after compilation

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar. I suppose I'm confused about what you are trying to do. Are you trying to add that mask somewhere in the network and then have additional layers stacked on the filtered image? Or are you trying to take the output, apply the mask and then use the filtered image somewhere else for something else?

Comment: Some additional code and expected inputs and outputs would be valuable

Comment: Yes, the mask will later be multiplied with the input and more layers will follow. I am sorry I was that unclear, I'll try to improve it tomorrow. Thanks again.